# In pure Java 8 how does one specify a read-only XmlAttribute with JAXB annotation?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-8

That means I have some XML from which the attribute selectedForCompare should only ever be unmarshalled (XML => Java Object), but never marshalled back to XML again:

```
<searchResult selectedForCompare="false" url="http://stackoverflow.com/blabla"/>
```

When read in this should be some java class such as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "searchResult")
class SearchResult {
  private String url;      
  private boolean selected;
  ..
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
  }

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public boolean isSelected() {
    return this.selected;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
  }

  @XmlAttribute(required = false)
  public void setSelectedForCompare(boolean selectedForCompare) {
    this.selected = selectedForCompare;
  }
}
```

So after unmarshalling I have a object such as:

```
searchResult.url = "http://stackoverflow.com/blabla"
searchResult.selected = false
```

And after (re-)marshalling I want the XML to look like:

```
<searchResult selected="false" url="http://stackoverflow.com/blabla" />
```

But currently it throws an Exception:

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: The property has a setter "void xx.yy.zz.SearchResult.setSelectedForCompare(boolean)" but no getter. For marshaller, please define getters.
com.sun.xml.bind.api.AccessorException: The property has a setter "void xx.yy.zz.SearchResult.setSelectedForCompare(boolean)" but no getter. For marshaller, please define getters.]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:331)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:257)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
```

How do I specify a read-only (from XML) attribute with annotation?

Comment: This is probably just me, but that sounds like a strange requirement for what is a object persistence api

Comment: Think of this problem as a backwards-compatible reading model, writing only the latest model-version out to XML.

Comment: See also [Object to XML, backward and forward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193561/)